# Font issue: Text is showing bold on Macbook - Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, font-face

I'm having font issues on Macbook Pro - Safari Browser. The issue is that one of the boxes have a kind of bold text, while the other two boxes have normal text. You can view the issue [here](http://www.fantasylab.no/ao/). If you look at the paragraph text inside the box called "VIP Lounge Oslo Airport" and the two other boxes you can see the text difference.

[image]

In Chrome, Firefox and Opera it looks like it should be, but not in Safari.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or any solution on how I can fix this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a style reset?

Comment: @christopher2007 No, I don't. Should I do that?

Comment: Yea, you always should. It resets the default styles of all browsers so that safari, chrome, opera, ie, ... will look the same in default. There are some good style resets out there. Google style reset, html5doctore, ... just google it.

Comment: It worked, perfectly, thank you!